# Algorithm - River Sizes - Code works but prompt complains memory leak

Tags: javascript, algorithm, memory-leaks, graph-traversal

Can people help to point out the problem with the code below? By inspecting the console.log, the code is working as intended, however, the prompt complains "Oops, your code timed out or ran out of memory. Check for infinite loops or memory leaks."

The code is not stuck in an infinite loop, so it must be about memory leaks. What is a memory leak, what is the problems with the code? Appreciated!

```
function riverSizes(matrix) {
let isVisitedMatrix = Array(matrix.length).fill(false).map(ele => Array(matrix[0].length).fill(false));
let lengthMatrix = [];
for (let row=0; row<matrix.length; row++)
    {
        for (let col=0; col<matrix[0].length; col++)
            {
                if (isVisitedMatrix[row][col] === true) continue;
                isVisitedMatrix[row][col] = true;
                if (matrix[row][col]===1)
                    {
                        const startNode = new Node(row, col);
                        const length = traverseNeighbour(matrix, [startNode], 1, isVisitedMatrix);
                        lengthMatrix.push(length);
                    }
            }
    }
return lengthMatrix; }


function traverseNeighbour(matrix, queue, currLength, isVisitedMatrix)
{
    if (queue.length === 0) return currLength;
    const startNode = queue.shift(); 
    const row = startNode.row;
    const col = startNode.col;
    isVisitedMatrix[row][col] = true;
    if (row-1>=0 && matrix[row-1][col]===1 && isVisitedMatrix[row-1][col]===false) 
        {
            currLength += 1;
            const top = new Node(row-1, col);
            queue.push(top);
        }
    if (row+1<matrix.length && matrix[row+1][col]===1 && isVisitedMatrix[row+1][col]===false) 
        {
            currLength += 1;
            const bottom = new Node(row+1, col);
            queue.push(bottom);
        }
    if (col-1>=0 && matrix[row][col-1]===1 && isVisitedMatrix[row][col-1]===false) 
        {
            currLength += 1;
            const left = new Node(row, col-1);
            queue.push(left);
        }
    if (col+1 < matrix[0].length && matrix[row][col+1]===1 && isVisitedMatrix[row][col+1]===false) 
        {
            currLength += 1;
            const right = new Node(row, col+1);
            queue.push(right);
        }
    return traverseNeighbour(matrix, queue, currLength, isVisitedMatrix);
}
class Node {
     constructor(_row, _col)
    {
        this.row = _row;
        this.col = _col;
    }
}
```

Here is the question.

> You're given a two-dimensional array (a matrix) of potentially unequal height and width containing only 0s and 1s. Each 0 represents land, and each 1 represents part of a river. A river consists of any number of 1s that
> are either horizontally or vertically adjacent (but not diagonally adjacent). The number of adjacent 1 s forming a river determine its size.
>
> Note that a river can twist. In other words, it doesn't have to be a straight vertical line or a straight horizontal line; it can be L-shaped, for example.
>
> Write a function that returns an array of the sizes of all rivers represented in the input matrix. The sizes don't need
> to be in any particular order.

Sample Input

```
matrix = [
   [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0 ,1],
   [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
]
```

Sample Output

```
[1, 2, 2, 2, 5] // The numbers could be ordered differently.

// The rivers can be clearly seen here:
// [
//   [1, , , 1, ],
//   [1, , 1, , ],
//   [, , 1, , 1],
//   [1, , 1, , 1],
//   [1, , 1, 1, ],
// ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try marking the visited right before adding the node to the queue so that you can ensure that you only add a node to the queue once. Right now, you mark the nodes once they dequeue, so your queue is probably getting extremely big.

By the way, this whole "traverse a 2d array" stuff comes up a lot, so it's best to just memorize a simple dfs implementation like this:

```
const getRiverCount = map => {
    const sizes = [];
    const h = map.length;
    const w = map[0].length

    const dfs = (r, c) => {
        if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= h || c >= w || map[r][c] === 0) return 0;
        map[r][c] = 0;
        return dfs(r + 1, c) + dfs(r - 1, c) + dfs(r, c + 1) + dfs(r, c - 1) + 1;
    }
    for (let r = 0; r < h; r++) {
        for (let c = 0; c < w; c++) {
            if (map[r][c] === 1) sizes.push(dfs(r, c));
        }
    }
    return sizes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the code isn't error-free (previously it repetitively adds nodes already in the queue to the queue again if that node is also neighbour with new nodes). After I edited the code, it passed all the tests :)

```
 function riverSizes(matrix) {
    const isVisitedMatrix = Array(matrix.length).fill(false).map(ele => Array(matrix[0].length).fill(false));
    let lengthMatrix = [];
    for (let row=0; row<matrix.length; row++)
        {
            for (let col=0; col<matrix[0].length; col++)
                {
                    if (isVisitedMatrix[row][col] === true) continue;

                    isVisitedMatrix[row][col] = true;
                    if (matrix[row][col]===1)
                        {
                            const startNode = new Node(row, col);
                            const length = traverseNeighbour(matrix, [startNode], 0, isVisitedMatrix);
                            lengthMatrix.push(length);
                        }
                }
        }
    return lengthMatrix;}

function traverseNeighbour(matrix, queue, currLength, isVisitedMatrix)
{
    if (queue.length === 0) return currLength;

    const startNode = queue.shift();
    currLength += 1;
    const row = startNode.row;
    const col = startNode.col;
    isVisitedMatrix[row][col] = true;
    
    if (row-1>=0 && matrix[row-1][col]===1 && isVisitedMatrix[row-1][col]===false) 
        {
            const top = new Node(row-1, col);
            isVisitedMatrix[row-1][col] = true;
            queue.push(top);
        }

    if (row+1<matrix.length && matrix[row+1][col]===1 && isVisitedMatrix[row+1][col]===false) 
        {
            const bottom = new Node(row+1, col);
            isVisitedMatrix[row+1][col] = true;
            queue.push(bottom);
        }

    if (col-1>=0 && matrix[row][col-1]===1 && isVisitedMatrix[row][col-1]===false) 
        {
            const left = new Node(row, col-1);
            isVisitedMatrix[row][col-1] = true;
            queue.push(left);
        }

    if (col+1 < matrix[0].length && matrix[row][col+1]===1 && isVisitedMatrix[row][col+1]===false) 
        {
            const right = new Node(row, col+1);
            isVisitedMatrix[row][col+1] = true;
            queue.push(right);
        }
    return traverseNeighbour(matrix, queue, currLength, isVisitedMatrix);}

class Node {
     constructor(_row, _col)
    {
        this.row = _row;
        this.col = _col;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).